# How to Display the Page Number Only (No Header) for Chapter Pages; Header Only, Elsewhere

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\thispagestyle{empty}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes line under header.

\lhead[{\emph{{\Large{\thepage}}}}]{LEFT}
\chead[{\emph{{\Large{MIDDLE}}}}]
{{\emph{\Large{MIDDLE}}}}
\rhead[RIGHT]{{\emph{{\Large{\thepage}}}}}

\chapter*{CHAPTER 1}\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter*{CHAPTER 2}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter*{CHAPTER 3}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Aside from the fist page (Chpater 1) in which I have removed both the header and the page number at the bottom by `\thispagestyle{empty}`, the remaining seven pages contain both a header and a page number at the bottom of each page.

QUESTION: How may the above code be modified in order that for pages 2-8: No header appears for `\chapter` pages (pgs 4,7; just a page number centered at the bottom of the page), whilst only the header appears (no page number at the bottom) for non-chapter pages (pgs 2, 3, 5, 6, 8)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `\pagestyle{fancyplain}`. It is obsolete, and it messes up your chapter opening pages. And use modern `fancyhdr` commands like `\fancyhead`, this is much clearer.

Then the chapter pages automatically get the `plain` pagestyle, which is what you want.
I also removed the `\thispagestyle{empty}`, because I guess you would want the page number also on the first page. If not, just keep it.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
%\thispagestyle{empty}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes line under header.

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\Large \thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{LEFT}
\fancyhead[RE]{RIGHT}
\fancyhead[C]{\emph{\Large MIDDLE}}
\fancyfoot{}

\chapter*{CHAPTER 1}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter*{CHAPTER 2}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter*{CHAPTER 3}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for posting this answer. The only question I have is how may I remove the lower page number on the Chapter 1 page? I tried un-commenting `%\thispagestyle{empty}`, but for some reason that doesn't work.

Comment: All seems to be fine, if, as Werner pointed out in a comment to another answer, that if I include `\thispagestyle{empty}` before the first `\chapter*`, that will accomplish what I am looking for.

Comment: You had two `%\thispagestyle{empty}`s.