# How to Selectively Remove the Header and Have the Page Number Only Appear at the Bottom of the Page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr, page

I am working on a document in which I make use of a header where the header displays the page number at the top of the page. There are, however, a small number of instances where I would like the header to disappear and the page number alone appear at the bottom of the page.

The following MWE

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\LARGE

\lhead[{\emph{{\Large{\thepage}}}}]{}
\chead[{\emph{{\Large{ }}}}]{{\emph{\Large{ }}}} \rhead[{}]{{\emph{{\Large{\thepage}}}}}


\chapter*{CHAPTER 1}
\lipsum[1]
    
\chapter*{CHAPTER 2}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter*{CHAPTER 3}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

produces the output

[image]

[image]

How may I, for example, make the header disappear on the first page and have the page number  (1, in this case) appear at the bottom of the page? I would like to have the flexibility of selectively doing this at other pages in the actual document as well.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/631556/113546

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Yes; but unless I'm wrong, I thought your answer in that post was more of a global adjustment throughout the document. How might one modify your answer to drop the page number to the bottom of the page only once or twice and not necessarily at the beginning of each new chapter?

Comment: Not that chapter uses `\thispagestyle{plain}` which is not the same as fancyplain.  There is only one fancy pagestyle and the package changes its definition as needed.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I have placed `\thispagestyle{plain}` in the code pertaining to the first page where I want no header but the page number to appear at the bottom---but it does not work---I still get the header for page 1. Perhaps you will consider modifying the MWE and posting it with the output as an answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I erroneously thought you wanted the special pagestyle (which is the standard pagestyle 'plain') on the first page of all chapters.

I now made a special page style 'nohead' to get what you want, and then you use `\thispagestyle{nohead}`.

I also changed the syntax to use the modern commands, and please, don't use `\pagestyle{fancyplain}`, this is deprecated. I also removed some unnecessary braces.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
% definitions for \pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\emph{\Large \thepage}}
% Same for \pagestyle{plain} - used for first chapter pages.
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\emph{\Large \thepage}}
}
\fancypagestyle{nohead}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\emph{\Large \thepage}}
}

\begin{document}
\LARGE

\chapter*{CHAPTER 1}
\thispagestyle{nohead}
\lipsum[1]
    
\chapter*{CHAPTER 2}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter*{CHAPTER 3}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\thispagestyle{plain}` on the pages where you do not want headers.

```
pagestyle{headings}
...
\chapter{First} % by default set with plain page style

several pages of text % set with headings page style

\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain}

more pages of text, the first set with plain page style, others with headings

\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
more pages of text set with plain style 

\newpage
\pagestyle{headings}
And so on and so forth
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot figure out what you mean. I want the first page in the MWE to display only the page number at the bottom of the page---the header OK on the other two pages. I have taken what you said: "Use `\thispagestyle{plain}` on the pages where you do not want headers." but it does not work when I apply it to the first page---I still get the header. Perhaps you will modify the MWE so that I can see what you mean. Thank you.